# "ar" tool allows creation of an empty library

Tags: linux, compilation, binutils, unix-ar

The classical "ar" tool from Binutils does not fail if some library specified in the command line does not exist.
It shows only the message "ar: <_library_name_>.a: No such file or directory", but the return code is zero.
This makes sometimes very hard to analyze build issues, because one spends a lot of time to find why some functions are missing in the resulting binary.

Why such a behavior? Really the most Linux users find that correct? Why not adding at least an option to fail?

```
ar -V
GNU ar (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ ar unknown.a 2>/dev/null || echo 'ko'
ko

$ ar -V
GNU ar (GNU Binutils) 2.28.0.20170506
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Likely your version of `ar` is too old.

Comment: Probably, I have to elaborate the reproduction conditions. I run the command this way:

$ ar -r result.a \`cat /tmp/00000000.lnk_11310\`
cat: /tmp/00000000.lnk_11310: No such file or directory
ar: creating result.a

$ cat result.a
!<arch>

Normally the file /tmp/00000000.lnk_11310 should contain the list of *.o files, but when it gets empty (due to another issue) then "ar" produces the empty library.